# PHP searching array

Tags: php

I am creating a contact form, which needs to change the sendto address based on an entered postal code.

I have an array of postal codes which I can search trough, so that I know if the postal code entered is actually in the array.

Here's how I search trough the array:

```
$districts = json_decode('{
 "district" : [ 
 { "name": "District A", "email": "abc@example.com", "url": "district-a", "postalcodes": ["3311AA","3311AB"] },
 { "name": "District B", "email": "xyz@example.com", "url": "district-b", "postalcodes": ["3317EA","3317EB","3317EC"] },
 ]
}',true);

$results = array_filter($districts['district'], function($district) {
    $key = array_search('3311AB', $district['postalcodes']);
  return $key;
});

var_dump($results);
```

Now I need to return the email address, based on in which District the postal code is found.

How would I search for, for example, postal code `3311AB` and return the email adress of the district to which it belongs?

Comment: you have incorrect json, so json_decode return false. Delete comma `["3317EA","3317EB","3317EC"] },`

Comment: @Dev I think it's just because of trimmed JSON structure

Comment: ok) I've just tried to run and got error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of returning key of postal code, you need to return `$district['email']`

```
$emails = [];

foreach ($districts['district'] as $district) {
    if (in_array('3311AB', $district['postalcodes'])) {
        $emails[] = $district['email'];
    }
}

var_dump($emails);
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae3a7e8b9b582bcc32e50a4ba811455c7ecfd7f9)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed :) Cheers!